# Deprecation warning for np.ptp

Tags: python, pandas, future-warning

I'm using Python and when using the following code

```
df['timestamp'] = df.groupby(["id"]).timestamp.transform(np.ptp)
```

I'm getting the warning `FutureWarning: Method .ptp is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use numpy.ptp instead.`. `df` is a Pandas DataFrame and `timestamp` and id are `columns`. I think `np.ptp` is causing this warning.

What do I have to change?

Comment: It is something that pandas needs to adjust itself to. You can temporarily ignore the warning and wait for a fix or use something like `df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: np.ptp(x.to_numpy()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the ***Method .ptp*** is being deprecated in favor of (from what I've read) the ***function np.ptp()*** so you can either set warnings to false in order to not read it, or replace the method with the function as numpy seems to suggest.

If you wish to supress the warnings, you can try with:
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore') or warnings.simplefilter('ignore', FutureWarning) if it's only FutureWarning you are ignoring.

Comment: Alright, but does using np.ptp() inside transform work? That means df['timestamp'] = df.groupby(["id"]).timestamp.transform(np.ptp())

Comment: It should be accepted yes, the warning is tellign that in a future it will not work and you'll have to use the function instead of the method, most probably with a lambda or apply function, with a np.ptp - transform inside it.

Comment: Great, thanks. By the way, how can I set the warning to false?

Comment: Edited in the answer :)